# Internal links to a parked domain + SEO

Tags: wordpress, seo, indexing, nofollow, parking

I'm working on a site where the client has 2 domains since he wants to separate his clinic and his teaching materiel but both sites are linked to another. The client also wants to manage the site himself, so I opted for a WordPress backend.

His domains will look like so:
www.myclinicinfo.com
www.myteachinginfo.com

Using the one backend, we though we would park a domain on the other and have links from myclinicinfo.com to myteachinginfo.com.

From research, I've come across the supposition that my pages should be indexed, but nofollow which would prevent search engines to flag my content, which honestly seems logical to me.

Would this be good or bad? Is there another solution to this kind of issue?

Thank you all !

Comment: Would the two domains be pointing to the same content?

Comment: The two domains do have similar content, but not exactly the same.

I've used Ennui's answer to get to the desired point and I've found a working solution using this quick trick :

http://carlorizzante.com/2011/301-redirect-made-simple/

Thanks for the quick reply. Hopes this will help you one day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one domain is parked on top of the other one (so typing either URL takes you to the same place) search engines will consider this duplicate content.  Pick a primary domain and implement a 301 redirect from the secondary domain to primary in htaccess or similar, or split the two sites so that they interlink seamlessly but there is no duplication of content (e.g. not parking).

Comment: Hello Ennui,

Thanks for the quick reply. Following your response, I came across this trick which works perfectly. 

http://carlorizzante.com/2011/301-redirect-made-simple/

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction !

D.